# Js/jQuery - This code sets a size to a variable, any way to make it responsive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive

A non-programmer here, looking for help. :) 
I've been searching for a way to make two circles spin inside a larger circle, in a very particular fashion, and I found [some code](http://jsfiddle.net/W69s6/20/) which I managed to tweak to get exactly the effect I wanted:

[image]

However, the full width of it is 400px (I need it to be so), and the problem is that the code defines the radius and positioning values in absolute, so if the browser goes below 400px width, it can't be adjusted:

```
var r = 101;
var xcenter = 100;
var ycenter = 100;
var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));
```

Now, I would be content if I could simply scale this whole thing for browsers < 400px down to

```
var r = 71;
var xcenter = 70;
var ycenter = 70;
var newLeft = Math.floor(xcenter + (r * Math.cos(t)));
var newTop = Math.floor(ycenter + (r * Math.sin(t)));
```

But I haven't the slightest clue how to go about implementing that responsiveness, or even if it's possible to do in real time (without having to refresh the browser, cos I'd like it to be resize-proof).

Here is the full fiddle of what I have: http://jsfiddle.net/29or8u76/3/

So... can someone help me out? Cos I don't really speak javascript at all :) Thanksss!

Comment: This logic is already recursively calling the same functions over and over.  Notice how the function at the end of both of the animates re-calls the same function that it is contained in? (red() and blue()).  Given this fact, really the only change you need to do is add an if to both of the methods and check if the `$(window).width() < 400` and if it is, adjust the variables to be what they should be.  EDIT: This does not account for any changes that the css may also need to account for, however.

Comment: But doesn't the $(window).width() method fail to adjust to a browser resize?

Comment: No, the `width()` method should give you the width of the element.  Provided you do not have css that forces the page to stay a certain minimum width, it will shrink as you resize the browser, and that method will reflect the change.  http://jsfiddle.net/237wynuh/  You can resize the iframe to see it.

Comment: Ok thanks! I think I got it to work! 
http://jsfiddle.net/a1qzk59v/
Although it is a very messy and repetitive code, you are right. If you have suggestions how to make it more compact, I'm listening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not directly answer your question, but here's an example using only CSS.
I've used percentages to keep everything responsive to the container width.

The inner circles rotate around their [origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) by using [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation), which uses [`transform`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

The pulsing of the outer circle is just for demonstration purposes, to show how the size of the inner circles are relative to their container.

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: pulse 5s 0s linear infinite;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: spin 3s 0s linear infinite;
}

#blue {
  top: 0;
  left: 25%;
  transform-origin: center bottom;
  background-color: #00f;
}

#red {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 25%;
  transform-origin: center top;
  background-color: #f00;
}

@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="circle" id="blue"></div>
  <div class="circle" id="red"></div>
</div>
```

---

EDIT:

To ensure that the *contents* of the circles don't rotate, I've used a slightly different method that animates the circles in orbit around the container's center.

This method is based on [a tutorial by Zoltan Howryluk](https://www.useragentman.com/blog/2013/03/03/animating-circular-paths-using-css3-transitions/).

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: pulse 5s 0s linear infinite;
}

.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  top: 25%;
  left: 25%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform-origin: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.circle span {
  font-size: 10px;
  color: white;
}

#blue {
  background-color: #00f;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  animation: orbit1 3s 0s linear infinite;
}

#red {
  background-color: #f00;
  transform: translateY(50%);
  animation: orbit2 3s 0s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes orbit1 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(50%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes orbit2 {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translateX(-50%) rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg) translateX(-50%) rotate(-360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0% {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
  50% {
    width: 10%;
    padding-bottom: 10%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="circle" id="blue"><span>BLUE</span></div>
  <div class="circle" id="red"><span>RED</span></div>
</div>
```

Before deciding on this method, I recommend considering [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/) and [vendor prefixes](http://shouldiprefix.com/) for various CSS3 functionality. For simplicity, I haven't included any vendor prefixes here.

Comment: That is really smooth! Sadly I can't really use it because in the end there will be text inside the circles, and in this method, (I just tried it out), the text rotates with the circles, while with js it doesn't. (I didn't mention that before because it didn't cross my mind that it would matter and I wanted to keep it simple.) But thanks for the creative approach, it's really neat, I'll save this idea for the future :)

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. Accordingly, I added an alternative method to my answer.

Comment: I like this. THANK YOU!